# How to get Image URI by intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in Android 10 and above

Tags: android, android-camera

FOR MODERATORS: I know there are already questions like this but all of those approaches endup giving bitmap through `data.getExtra("data")` which is actually just `thumbnail`. I want to get URI not bitmap and I need to get URI of ACTUAL IMAGE not its thumbnail with approach available in `2021`. PLEASE CONSIDER THIS BEFORE TAGGING QUESTION AS DUPLICATE!

I am getting image from camera and its working fine on lower devices but its giving null in data when `onActivityResult` is called only in Android 10 and 11.

That's what I am doing

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA)
```

Here is my onActivityResult

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            data?.data?.let { uri ->
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Got URI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/ShashankPednekar/ImagePicker-and-Compression and also check https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility you should get uri in 10 and 11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This approach worked for me

In `Manifest` file

```
     <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
     ...
     </application
```

created a file `/res/xml/file_paths.xml` and specified path in that

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

In my `activity`

created a global variable `var cameraPhotoFilePath: Uri? = null`

this is how I started Camera acitivity for results

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFileInAppDir()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    null
                }

                photoFile?.also { file ->
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        "com.example.android.provider",
                        file
                    )
                    cameraPhotoFilePath = photoURI
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                }
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA)
```

here is a helper function that i used in above code

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFileInAppDir(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imagePath = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        return   File(imagePath, "JPEG_${timeStamp}_" + ".jpg")
    }
```

At the end in `onActivityResult` thats how I got image Uri

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == ACTION_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        cameraPhotoFilePath?.let { uri -> 
            // here uri is image Uri that was captured by camera
        }
    }
```

Comment: Took me days to find a solution on getting the imageUri but didn't try yours because there is only 1 upvote. Now when i tried your code, it works on the first time, no bug at all. People should upvote this as a solution to reach more people

Comment: But it doesn't work some devices such as HONOR 9X Android 10.0.0
REALME C11 Android 10.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your own uri (path) to intent with action `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`

```
putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    applicationContext,
    "$packageName.your_file_provider",
    File("path/to")
))
addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

More info about [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

Comment: can you please explain how to access that fileprovider from extra in `onActivityResult`

Comment: in `onActivityResult` you don't need to do anything because the provided intent path is where the image will appear

Comment: You you self dont need to use the file provider. Just use `File("path/to")`. And if you wanna share the picture just build up the uri again from that path.

Comment: @blackapps the secure way is to use FileProvider. As for me on older versions of Android `File("path/to")` did not work

Answer (score 0):

Android developer have good documentation about how to get full sized photos . You can also get the uri of full size image .Please visit this link [Get full size image](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

Comment: The link is broken. Please edit your answer.