# imageUri retrieved from FileProvider.getUriForFile() is set on imageView but shows empty ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm trying to display the image in `ImageView` received from Camera `Intent`, but the ImageView displays an empty image.

It shows error saying ImageView unable to open content, and failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

```
W/ImageView: Unable to open content: content://com.example.mobilee_commerceapp/my_images/JPEG_20211230_214226_1746483040936834961.jpg
    android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
```

Below is the code:

```
private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        val photoFile: File? = try {
            createImageFile()
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            null
        }
        photoFile?.also {
            Log.d(TAG, "Success creating file")
            Log.d(TAG, "PATH is " + it.absolutePath)
            cameraPhotoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                requireContext(),
                "com.example.mobilee_commerceapp",
                it
            )
        }
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        getCameraResult.launch(takePictureIntent)
}
```

**getCameraResult()**. cameraPhotoURI is global variable.

```
private val getCameraResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
            if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                binding.profilePicIv.setImageURI(cameraPhotoURI)
            }
        }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mobilee_commerceapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
    android:required="false"/>

    <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.mobilee_commerceapp"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Comment: I need the imageUri to save the Uri to FirebaseStorage, is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

**Manifest file**

```
<manifest package="your.package.name">
<queries>
<intent>
    <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
</intent>
</queries>
</manifest>
```

add for android 10 :

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**button click code**

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

**onActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
```

Comment: Is this your working code?

Comment: My mistake, but i need to get the `imageUri` for me to write to `FirebaseStorage`. How can i do that if the `imageUri` can't be accessed?

Comment: check this link to upload your uri in firebaseStorage :https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution in this post [How to get Image URI by intent MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in Android 10 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166944/how-to-get-image-uri-by-intent-mediastore-action-image-capture-in-android-10-and). Followed its way and URI can be retrieved and set to imageView. Other solution is either outdated or not in kotlin.